# Dependency Injection in Spring failed

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject some objects in my web application using spring dependency injection.

In EtudiantServiceImpl class (which has `@Service` annotation) I have :

```
@Autowired
private IEtudiantDao etudiantDao;
```

And in EtudiantAction class (which has `@Service` annotation) I have :

```
@Autowired
private EtudiantServiceImpl etudiantService;
@Autowired
public Etudiant etudiant;
```

But when I run my application I get this error message:

```
2015-01-02 06:14:38,741 ERROR (org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher:38) - Exception occurred during processing request: Unable to instantiate Action, tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction,  defined for 'etudiants' in namespace '/'Error creating bean with name 'tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction.etudiantService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
Unable to instantiate Action, tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction,  defined for 'etudiants' in namespace '/'Error creating bean with name 'tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction.etudiantService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:316)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
    at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1085)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:658)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1556)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1513)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction.etudiantService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:287)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1073)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:373)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.autoWireBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:203)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:183)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:154)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultActionFactory.buildAction(DefaultActionFactory.java:22)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:141)
    at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.web.EtudiantAction.etudiantService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:506)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [tp.ihm.gestionEtudiants.service.EtudiantServiceImpl] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:924)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:793)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:707)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:478)
    ... 38 more
```

And this is the application context file :

```
<!-- Configure jdbc.properties -->
    <bean id="propertyConfigurer"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
        p:location="/WEB-INF/jdbc.properties" />

    <!-- Data Source configuration -->
    <bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

        <property name="driverClassName">
            <value>${jdbc.driverClassName}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="url">
            <value>${jdbc.databaseurl}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="username">
            <value>${jdbc.username}</value>
        </property>
        <property name="password">
            <value>${jdbc.password}</value>
        </property>
   </bean>

    <!-- Configure hibernate session factory -->    
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="configLocation">
            <value>classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml</value>
        </property>
        <property name="configurationClass">            
            <value>org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration</value>        
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${jdbc.dialect}</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
    <!-- Run SQL queries in transactions -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

## Edit1:

After I added this line to my spring configuration file :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="/" />
```

It solved that problem, but now I'm getting another error message :

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'genericDaoImpl' defined in file [C:\Users\Aimad\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\TP_WEB_GestionEtudiants\WEB-INF\classes\tp\generic\dao\GenericDaoImpl.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1422)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:518)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:192)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:585)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:282)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:204)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4772)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5196)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'sessionFactory' or 'hibernateTemplate' is required
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.checkDaoConfig(HibernateDaoSupport.java:118)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DaoSupport.afterPropertiesSet(DaoSupport.java:44)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
    ... 21 more
```

And this is the `GenericDaoImpl` class:

```
@Repository
public class GenericDaoImpl<T, PK extends Serializable> extends HibernateDaoSupport implements GenericDao<T,PK> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public GenericDaoImpl(){
    }

    public GenericDaoImpl(final Class<T> entityClass){
        this.entityClass = entityClass;
    }

    public T getEntity(PK id) {
        return (T) getHibernateTemplate().get(entityClass, id);
    }

    public List<T> getAll(){
        return getHibernateTemplate().loadAll(entityClass);
    }

    public PK save(T entity) {
        return (PK) getHibernateTemplate().save(entity);
    }

    public void delete(PK id) {
        if(getEntity(id) != null)
            getHibernateTemplate().delete(getEntity(id));
    }

    public void update(T entity) {
        getHibernateTemplate().update(entity);

    }
```

Comment: The message is clear: You don't have a bean to inject. If you're using `@Service` and primarily XML configuration, you need to activate annotation processing and component scanning.

Comment: How you are configuring your beans? How spring looks for it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to mention to auto scan for all the beans.

Please specify below configuration in Spring configuration xml file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.x.y.z" />
```

[Tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-scanning-components/)

[Here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch06s02.html) is programmatically configuration for auto scan.

Comment: please see the modification I made to my post

Answer (score -1):

Not sure but are you using getter and setter for the private fields sometime it throws this kind of error in the situation where you are not having getter and setter.